# How to perform quantile transformation or normalization using scikit learn preprocessing modules on river stream object

Tags: scikit-learn, data-preprocessing

How to perform quantile transformation or normalization using sklearn.preprocesing library on river stream object?

The following a piece of reproducible code, that results in an error:

```
from river.stream import iter_pandas
from river.metrics import Accuracy
from river import metrics
from river import stream
from river import ensemble
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer 

students=pd.DataFrame()
students['r_no']=[1,2,3,4,5]
students['course_no']=['CS_123','CS_456','CS_890','CS_678','CS_123']
students['pass']=[1,1,0,0,1]

x_students=students.drop(['pass'],axis=1)
y_students=students['pass']

c1 = ensemble.AdaptiveRandomForestClassifier(split_confidence=0.01,tie_threshold=0.07, seed=123)
c2 = ensemble.AdaptiveRandomForestClassifier(split_confidence=0.01,tie_threshold=0.07, seed=123)

trans_st1 = QuantileTransformer(n_quantiles=3, random_state=123)
trans_st2 = QuantileTransformer(n_quantiles=3, output_distribution='normal', random_state=456)

strm_st1=iter_pandas(X=x_students,y=y_students)
strm_st2=iter_pandas(X=x_students,y=y_students)

metric1 = metrics.Accuracy()
metric2 = metrics.Accuracy()

y_preds_st1 = []
y_preds_st2 = []

for ((xi1, yi1),(xi2, yi2)) in zip(strm_st1,strm_st2):

   new_xi1=trans_st1.fit_transform(xi1)

   new_xi2=trans_st2.fit_transform(xi2)

   y_pred1 = c1.predict_one(xi1)

   y_pred2 = c2.predict_one(xi2)

   c1.learn_one(xi1, yi1)

   c2.learn_one(xi2, yi2)

   metric1.update(y_pred=y_pred1, y_true=yi1)

   metric2.update(y_pred=y_pred2, y_true=yi2)

   y_preds_st1.append(y_pred1)

   y_preds_st2.append(y_pred2)

   print(f"Accuracy for c1: {metric1.get()}")

   print(f"Accuracy for c2: {metric2.get()}")
```

The above code generates the following error:

```
TypeError   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-145-5db072b0adbf> in <module>()
      7 for ((xi1, yi1),(xi2, yi2)) in zip(strm_st1,strm_st2):
      8 
----> 9   new_xi1=trans_st1.fit_transform(xi1)
     10 
     11   new_xi2=trans_st2.fit_transform(xi2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    529                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    530                 else:
--> 531                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    532             except ComplexWarning:
    533                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```

How can this be rectified?

Comment: Please post the full error race - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: The complete error trace has been provided, please have a look